# "System unavailable please try later " - error in PAYPAL MPL SDK in iphone

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-mpl

I am integrating Paypal into an iphone application using the Adaptive payment option from `PAYPAL MPL SDK`, but am getting this error message:

> System Unavailable . please try again later

I used PAYPAL MPL SDK downloaded from this link: https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

It was actually a temporary issue from Paypal side, that too only in Sandbox. Now it's up and working, I posted a similar question that time:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915835/paypal-mpl-version-2-1-7-in-ios-has-stopped-working-since-20th-jan-2016-is-it

Comment: I am facing the same issue right now. Any solution ?

Comment: i am also facing same problem. any help appreciated

Comment: Same time of the year when I posted the question, last year. Maybe PayPal makes changes at this time of the year.
Try contacting the Paypal support team.